# Oracle SQL - ORA-00904: "IPA"."CHECK_ID": invalid identifier

Tags: sql, oracle

When I run the below, I get the error: `ORA-00904: "IPA"."CHECK_ID": invalid identifier`

However, the table in question does exist and does have the column. Any ideas?

```
SELECT *
  FROM ap_invoices_all aia
       INNER JOIN ap_invoice_lines_all aila
          ON aia.invoice_id = aila.invoice_id
       INNER JOIN ap_invoice_distributions_all ida
          ON     aila.invoice_id = ida.invoice_id
             AND aila.line_number = ida.invoice_line_number
       INNER JOIN ap_invoice_payments_all ipa
          ON aia.invoice_id = ipa.invoice_id
       INNER JOIN "poz_suppliers_v" psv ON aia.vendor_id = psv.vendor_id
       INNER JOIN "poz_supplier_sites_v" pssv
          ON     aia.vendor_id = pssv.vendor_id
             AND aia.party_site_id = pssv.party_site_id
       INNER JOIN "gl_code_combinations" gcc
          ON ida.dist_code_combination_id = gcc.code_combination_id,
       iby_payments_all ibypa
       INNER JOIN "ap_checks_all" aca
          ON     aca.check_id = ipa.check_id
             AND aca.payment_id = ibypa.payment_id
       INNER JOIN fun_all_business_units_v fun ON aia.org_id = fun.bu_id
```

AP_INVOICE_PAYMENTS_ALL definition https://docs.oracle.com/cd/E51367_01/financialsop_gs/OEDMF/AP_INVOICE_PAYMENTS_ALL_tbl.htm

If I remove the offending line, then I get an error saying `AIA.ORG_ID` is an invalid identifier

However if I do the following, it does not error:

```
SELECT *
  FROM ap_invoices_all aia
       INNER JOIN fun_all_business_units_v fun ON aia.org_id = fun.bu_id
```

It's almost like the alias *has* to be just before the join

Comment: It's a throwaway virtual machine on my personal laptop as just wanted to run one script. Have amended script to not show it - but it still doesn't help with the issue.

Comment: You have the alias `IPA` defined twice, for `AP_INVOICE_PAYMENTS_ALL` and `IBY_PAYMENTS_ALL`. This, however, causes no error on a local tryout...

Comment: Have amended the alias and still an error

Comment: @pee2pee Please show the table structure of `ap_invoice_payments_all`

Comment: @pee2pee Are you referring `ipa.check_id` with double quotes or without double quotes?

Comment: Added table structure. The SQL is as you see it

Comment: @pee2pee Why not do a manual debugging by commenting out joins and tables by which you would be able to trace the error part.

Answer (score 2):

You are mixing join types; old-style Oracle joins (with a comma), and proper ANSI joins. That is causing the conditions to be checked in an order you don't expect, and some of the earlier aliases don't exist yet.

The parser is effectively trying to evaluate this part on its own first:

```
       iby_payments_all ibypa
       INNER JOIN "ap_checks_all" aca
          ON     aca.check_id = ipa.check_id
             AND aca.payment_id = ibypa.payment_id
       INNER JOIN fun_all_business_units_v fun ON aia.org_id = fun.bu_id
```

and within that snippet `ipa` and `aia` do not (yet) exist, hence the errors you see. If that part was OK on its own then that would be joined to the reset of the ANSI section, but it isn't getting that far because it's already seen errors. (I'm over-simplifying, and trying to figure out what the parser is actually doing is often a guessing-game... but that's the gist of the problem.)

Change the comma followed by `iby_payments_all ibypa` to a cross join:

```
...
       INNER JOIN "gl_code_combinations" gcc
          ON ida.dist_code_combination_id = gcc.code_combination_id,
       iby_payments_all ibypa
       INNER JOIN "ap_checks_all" aca
          ON     aca.check_id = ipa.check_id
             AND aca.payment_id = ibypa.payment_id
       INNER JOIN fun_all_business_units_v fun ON aia.org_id = fun.bu_id
```

fo

```
...
       INNER JOIN "gl_code_combinations" gcc
          ON ida.dist_code_combination_id = gcc.code_combination_id
       CROSS JOIN iby_payments_all ibypa
       INNER JOIN "ap_checks_all" aca
          ON     aca.check_id = ipa.check_id
             AND aca.payment_id = ibypa.payment_id
       INNER JOIN fun_all_business_units_v fun ON aia.org_id = fun.bu_id
```

which seems to be the equivalent of what you're doing; although it should be an inner join too if there are join conditions for that table too, obviously...

Comment: Thanks - using navicat to do the SQL so that's where it's from